# How to copy a file with line number in linux?

Tags: linux

I am noob, and not good at linux

I want to copy specific line(20~29) of the file that containing its original line number.

So, I need a new file starting with 20.

Just like this

20 ~~~
21 ~~~
22 ~~~
.
.
.
29 ~~~
(vertically)

I need your help.
Thanks

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526073/164309) should help you, if you want to the output to contain selected lines from the input, each line with the original line number. If this is the case, your question is terribly written, and you should improve it!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in many ways-

1. Using head- tail command-

`head -n 29 your_file.txt |tail -n -10 > new_file.txt`

2. Using sed command- is stream editor and it can perform lot’s of function on file like, searching, find and replace, insertion or deletion.

`sed -n '20,29p' your_file.txt > new_file.txt`

3. Using awk command- is used for selecting & manipulating data in a file or passed data passed in runtime

`awk 'NR>=20 && NR<=29' your_file.txt > new_file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
awk 'NR >= 10 && NR <= 20 { print NR,$0}' filename
```

This will read the file `filename` and print the line number (`NR`) followed by the line (`$0`). The conditions `NR >= 10` and `NR <= 20` allow you to choose which lines you want to extract.

If you want to save it in a file, you can redirect the output to a file like so:

```
awk 'NR >= 10 && NR <= 20 { print NR,$0}' filename > new_file
```

It will put the line numbers and the lines inside a new file called `new_file`.

`awk` is a powerfull program which can perform many operations on a text file/stream. I recommand you to learn how to use this tool if you want to achieve complicated things easily in linux.

Comment: Thank you!!  You are my savior